# How can I replace a #define macro I used to have in Objective-C in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macros

I've been using this macro in Objective-C:

```
#define     RGBA(r, g, b, a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:(a)]
```

I am trying to figure out how I can get the closest thing possible in swift. Any ideas?

Comment: How about making a function that wraps around Swift's syntax for creating a color, if it's too long for you?

Comment: In Swift, Apple has decided that macros make debugging harder. They want you to use a function instead.

Comment: ok, so no more macros. I see. thanks for the input

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An extension on `UIColor` is a valid option.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ r: Double, _ g: Double, _ b: Double, _ a: Double) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let white = UIColor(255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: This works thanks. Will this be visible to other classes now?, also, why did you add the "_" before each parameter in the function call?

Comment: the `_` allows you to skip the parameter names when calling the methods.

Comment: It might be just a swift 2.0 issue but you need to add CGFloat convert on the double values other wise you'll get an error that a double is not convertible to CGFloat

Answer (score 8):

In the global scope provide:

```
func RGBA (r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, a:CGFloat) {
  return UIColor (red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha: a)
}
```

and then use it with:

```
var theColor : UIColor = RGBA (255, 255, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I'll try this. I am not 100% sure I understand it, could you provide the full answer in code? thank you

Comment: Yes, but check out the Apple documentation for UIColor, specifically the init() functions with their Swift calling convention.

Comment: So I added what you suggested:     func RGBA (r:Int, g:Int, b:Int, a:Int) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:r/255.0,green:g/255.0,blue:b/255.0,alpha:a)
    } and also added the Return type -> UIColor. Compiler gave me an error saying: "Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments. The initializer in UIColor cannot take in Int, so I went ahead and changed the "Int" to "CGFloat" and it worked. I will mark @Gabriele Petronella's answer correct as it worked as is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to create a class method that returns the #define.

Example:

**.h file**

```
#define     RGBA(r, g, b, a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:(a)]
+ (UIColor*)RGBA:(CGFloat)r g:(CGFloat)g b:(CGFloat)b a:(CGFloat)a;
```

**.m file**

```
+ (UIColor*)RGBA:(CGFloat)r g:(CGFloat)g b:(CGFloat)b a:(CGFloat)a { return RGBA(r, g, b, a); }
```